# apply jquery on dynamically loaded html

Tags: jquery, css

**Description :**

I have a php code that loads all the user posts on the profile. Now there is a div in each post with a class of "new_text_post"

**What I want :**

what I want is that when all the posts load on the page the div with "new_text_post" class should be hidden which later on is being fade toggled (which is working perfectly). I dont know how to load that div remaining hidden and it should fadetoggle when I click.

**What have I tried**

1) I have tried to set its css property `visibility:hidden` but that hides it completely and never shows it even on fade toggle

2) I have used jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".new_text_post").hide();

});
```

but even that doesn't work ... I have been through this before but I can't remember how I solved it

Thats how I am loading the user posts

```
<?php 
while ($t = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo '<div class = "new_text_post">'.$t['post'].'<div>';
}

 ?>
```

.. Anyone ??

Comment: Use `display:none`, not visibility.

Comment: display none and on toggle you can set display show

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5ahckn7t/  ?

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on how you load the dynamic content.

in any case, you should hide the content **After** you load the content, and **Not** on page load.

if you use ajax, you need to hide it in the same `done` function:

```
done: function(){
    //...
    //add elements here
    //...

    //and then hide them
    $(".new_text_post").hide();
},
```

if you use the jQuery ajax extension `.load()`, then you need to wait until the load is complete:

```
.load(/*...load here...*/).promise().done(function(){
    $(".new_text_post").hide();
});
```

in any case, you need to hide them in the same place where you add them.

**UPDATE**

add a script block right after you load the posts, and there execute the jquery:

```
<?php 
    while ($t = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo '<div class = "new_text_post">'.$t['post'].'<div>';
    }
    //after adding all the posts, insert a script block with the hiding jQuery:
    echo "<script> $('.new_text_post').hide(); </script>"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get the question right, but do you mean something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/5ahckn7t/

A div with userposts is shown, but the new_text_post is hidden on default.

```
<div class="userpost">
    This is a div with userpost

    <div class="new_text_post">
        This is a div which is not always shown
    </div>
</div>
```

And JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".new_text_post").hide();
});


$('.userpost').on('click', function(){
   $('.new_text_post').show();
});
```

**Update**

Hm, still I think I don't get the question right, but maybe this was what you ment:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ahckn7t/1/

```
<div class="userpost">
    This is a div with userpost
</div>
<div class="new_text_post">
    This is a div which is not always shown
</div>
<div class="userpost">
    This is a div with userpost
</div>
<div class="new_text_post">
    This is a div which is not always shown
</div>
<div class="userpost">
    This is a div with userpost
</div>
<div class="new_text_post">
    This is a div which is not always shown
</div>

<button id="togglePost">Toggle new_text_post</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".new_text_post").hide();
});


$('#togglePost').on('click', function(){
   $('.new_text_post').show();
});
```

Comment: see i have updated my post .. now can u tell me what is wrong ??

Comment: Hm.. Maybe you you mean something like this. You can add the classes to the posts when you query them.. http://jsfiddle.net/5ahckn7t/1/

Comment: all I needed to do was use display:none that solved the problem.. thanx anyway :)

Comment: Display none is the same as hide()

Answer (score -2):

use parent selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body .new_text_post").hide();
});
```